# Linkedin API Limit of calls for Application

Tags: api, linkedin-api

I want like to use the Linkedin API with Application Authorization to use in my web application.
I would like to know what will be the limit of calls per day or per month.
Thank you

Comment: Do you have already see this page? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/api-guide/concepts/rate-limits

Comment: Yes but it doesn't specify the number of calls that an Application can make per day.